# Mongodb and nodejs validation form

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am very new to mongodb and nodejs as well. I want to do a login validation where my data from html page is fed to nodejs and checked for existence and then a message is sent to html. How do I do it.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    console.log('chut');
});
app.post('/appl', function (req, res) {
    var emai = req.body.email;
    var pas = req.body.key;



    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;

    //connect away
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/swapnil', function (err, db) { // change db name//
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to Database");

        //simple json record
        var document = {
            emailId: emai,
            password: pas
        };

        //insert record
        db.collection('register').find(document, function (err, records) {
            if (err) res.send('fail');
            else res.send('pass');
        });


    });
});
```

this was nodejs file.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-wrap" role="form" action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/appl" method="post" onsubmit="return vali()" id="login-form" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="key" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="key" id="key" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <p class="req" id="vaa"></p>
    </div> <a href="javascript:;" class="forget grey-text text-lighten-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".forget-modal" style="text-align:left;">Forgot your password?</a>

    <input type=submit> <a id="new" href="#" class="forget grey-text text-lighten-1">New User? Sign Up</a>

</form>
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow generally isn't the place for questions like this, however:

The most popular node authentication system is [passport](http://passportjs.org/).

Here's a [tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.VZvrrhNVhHw) for passport with mongoose.

Also, don't save your passwords in plain text or you'll end up [here](http://plaintextoffenders.com/).